# What does $\sum_{p|n} \chi_{-4}(p)$ count?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, dirichlet-character

Let $\chi_{-4}$ be the Dirichlet character defined by
$$ \chi_{-4}(m) = \begin{cases} 1, & m\equiv 1 \mod 4 \\
-1, &m \equiv 3 \mod 4\\
0, &m \equiv 0 \mod 2.\end{cases}$$
I know that
$$r_2(n)=4\sum_{d|n} \chi_{-4}(d)$$
counts the number of ways one can write $n$ as a sum of two squares. This got me curious as to what
$$\sum_{p|n} \chi_{-4}(p)$$
(p is prime) counts? Im looking for a quick reference or explanation. Thanks!

Comment: It's OEIS sequence [A005094](https://oeis.org/A005094) and given that it's sometimes negative, it's pretty clear that it does not count anything.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thank you!